# Javascript that shrinks navigation on page scroll with media queries?

Tags: javascript, scroll, navigation, media-queries, responsive

I'm using this W3Schools example to shrink the navigation on page scroll, which works, except I need the ability to fine tune responsive breakpoints beyond what's possible in the example.

Does anyone know how to modify this javascript to include media queries breakpoints?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_shrink_scroll.asp

```
// When the user scrolls down 80px from the top of the document, resize the navbar's padding and the logo's font size
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "80px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
```

In the example there's limited responsive support. I'm looking for a way to be more specific with the breakpoints using javascript, such as "this ID will have this style changed within these breakpoints" if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element that's targeted by ID to have its style changed within a breakpoint, why not just use a pure CSS media query?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

If you really want to use media queries within Javascript, however, you can use [matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Here's an example:

```js
// Define the media query
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');

// Add a listener to detect changes in the media query
mediaQuery.addListener(handleMediaQuery);

// Define the function to handle the media query
function handleMediaQuery(event) {
  if (event.matches) {
    // Code to run when the viewport width is 600px or less
  } else {
    // Code to run when the viewport width is greater than 600px
  }
}

// Call the function initially to handle the media query on page load
handleMediaQuery(mediaQuery);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I don't believe pure CSS provides the level of detail needed in this case, since it relies on using the "!important" property to override the javascript. Ideally there would be a way to use javascript to have different CSS styling applied to the navigation shrink depending on the breakpoints. Unfortunately I don't have the javascript knowledge to be able to write code that does this